# In a two-player Texas Hold'Em poker hand with blinds, which player posts the small blind?

Tags: poker

In a small-blind/big-blind poker game (I'm thinking of Texas Hold 'em, but I guess this question applies to any similarly structured poker game), how does the structure change when the games gets to the final two players?

So, for four+ players, it's:

[D] [SB] [BB] [UTG]* (pre-flop)

For three players, it's:

[D/UTG] [SB] [BB]

So, for two players, is it:

[D/BB] [SB/UTG]

*
[D] = Dealer
[SB]=Small Blind
[BB]=Big Blind
[UTG] = Under The Gun, i.e. first to act.

Comment: Here is another question that asks a similar question: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/texas-holdem-heads-up-blind-structure

Comment: Your question seems ambiguous. 

 - Is the dealer actually a player, or someone separate?  
 - Is the dealer  fixed at one person, or does deal rotate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Under practically all rules, the dealer posts the small blind and is first to act preflop. After the flop, the other player acts first.

Other rules have occasionally been implemented -- I believe Party Poker used to have this backwards preflop -- but this is almost universal. It is generally thought to lead to a better game with more action, as the small blind has a higher incentive to complete or raise when he has the benefit of acting last postflop.

Answer (score 0):

What your post describes, with the dealer posting the big blind, covers how I have always seen this scenario played, between various casinos in Biloxi, MS, USA and local games in Nashville TN and Atlanta GA.